# Cannot open jupyter notebook in VSCode

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

I recently switched to Visual Studio Code and would like to use Jupyter Notebooks. I have installed the `ms-python` extension, and also the `jupyter` package, as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_setting-up-your-environment).

However, after reloading, I did not have a command `Python: Create Blank New Jupyter Notebook`, and if I open existing notebooks, the HTML/CSS is shown instead of an actual notebook view. I haven't found anything related to this problem online yet.

Answer (score 2):

If Python extension is available, (if not install that extension) in VSCode, while the jupyter style file (cells beginning with # %%) is active:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type: **Export Current Python File as Jupyter Notebook**

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to fix this should be to save the file with an `.ipynb` ending, vs-code should then automatically start the notebook extension. You can also make sure that you activated a Python environment, then `Python: Create New Blank Jupyter Notebook` should appear.

An alternative I would recommend is editing notebooks following [this guide in the vs-code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py)

Comment: I can create a new one just fine, opening existing ones results in the error decribed in the OP

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the Jupyter extension is not maintained. I just use the python extension now. I received this info from the vscode notification in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Yes it's now part of the official Python extension, but it's really buggy lately

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good explanation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/data-science-tutorial

I fixed by setting enviroment and workspace using terminal and this tutorial. Do not afraid if your purpose isn't data science, anyway knowledge are useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found no answers online to solve it.
What I've tried:
1- re-load Vs Code;
2- choose Python interpreter on Command Pallet (Ctrl + Shift + P);
3- Create New Blanck Notebook on Command Pallet (Ctrl + Shift + P);
The editor would change to a notebook cell with Code and Markdown options if step 3 worked properly.
4- open your notebook (File > Open or Ctrl+Shift+E - if it is already part of your workspace).

Then I was able to run cells.

I believe it's not necessarily a Python Extension bug. But ended up giving up for now, because new little issues were showing up. I prefer using the python editor with `#%%` to create cells and run in Interactive Python.