# Can't open existing jupyter notebook in remote server using VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

This is related to this question

[Can't open jupyter notebook in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60968736/cant-open-jupyter-notebook-in-vscode)

Except my issue is that I can't open existing jupyter notebooks. Creating new ones works just fined, but opening saved notebooks results in

> Cannot open resource with notebook editor type 'jupyter-notebook', please check if you have the right extension installed or enabled.

Steps to reproduce:

1 Connect to a remote server.

2 Create a jupyter notebook. Write some cells. Save. Log out of remote server.

3 Reconnect to remote server, right click on jupyter notebook file -> open with -> Jupyter Notebook.

Result usually is

> Cannot open resource with notebook editor type 'jupyter-notebook', please check if you have the right extension installed or enabled.

Occasionally it opens correctly, but most of the time, it does not.

However, if I create new .ipynb file, Jupyter starts up correctly. If I then try to open the file with Jupyter, I still get the same error.

This error does not seem to be reproduced with I am working locally; not on a remote server. I am using the remote-ssh extension to log into the remote server.